# COMPOSITE KEY HANDLING IN HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate

I have one hbm which holds the composite key .I am able to fetch and search the record .But when i am trying to save it gives the error  invalid column index .
I think it was taking the composite key as a column can u tell me how can i prevent it to save .
In its pojo i made a static inner class for the composite key .
I have make that "transient" but it is not working . i even remove the getter and setter of the PK.but hibernate throws the exception "INVALID COLUMN INDEX"...........

```
    <composite-id class="com.TRIAL.entity.MOption$ID" mapped="true">
        <key-property name="id" column="OPT_ID" type="java.lang.String" />
        <key-property name="sequence" column="SEQ" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <key-property name="rBeginDate" column="RC_BEG_TS" type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
        <key-property name="rEndDate" column="RC_END_TS" type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
        <key-property name="rState" column="RC_STAT_C" type="java.lang.String" />
    </composite-id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate, this error message means that you mapped the same column twice. Check your column names in the whole mapping.

Comment: I was adding as a property too.So i set that as insert false ,and problem was solved .